# How to redirect to inside and external pages from ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am new to react and trying to route the user to a new page (within and external) if a certain condition is not met. My snippet below works but I not confident that it is the correct approach.

Could you please have a look and let me know if there is a more efficient way to do it. I want to redirect user automatically when the URL does not have an argument or has an invalid argument.

Thanks

```
export default class extends Component {
  static getInitialProps({ query: { city, state } }) {
    return { city: city, state: state };
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    if (!this.props.city) {
       Router.push('INTERNAL URL')
    } else {
        if (this.props.city === "augusta") {
          window.location = 'https://www.google.com'
        }
    }
   }

 render() {
     if (!this.props.city ||this.props.city === "augusta"){
       return null
     }else{
        return(
           <div>...</div>
        )
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: What is the version of nextjs you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [react-router](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router).  `react-router`. Try if this works

```
import { Route } from 'react-router';

export default YourPageComponent extends React.Component {

    //no need to use static method as react-router provides a props called 'match' allows you get back param from URL
    static getInitialProps({ query: { city, state } }) {
      return { city: city, state: state };
    }

    componentDidMount = () => {
       this.handleRedirect();
    }

    //put this function in the related component in componentDidMount
    handleRedirect = () => {

       const {match: { params }} = this.props;
       console.log(params.state, params.city);

       //do your logic here
       if (params.city !== "augusta"){
           window.location.href = 'https://google.com'; 
           return null;
       }
    }


  }
```

In app.js

```
   render() {
       <Switch>
           {/* take URL path as a condition to go to which page */}
           <Route path='/:city/:state' component={YourPageComponent}/>
           <Route path='/' component={/* put your default component here */}/>
        </Switch>
    }
```

Comment: check my modified answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **react-router-dom**. Example from https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Link
} from "react-router-dom";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/users">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/about">
            <About />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/users">
            <Users />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/">
            <Home />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to use react-router-dom. 
Once you set up the router on the top of your application you can use the Router methods in your child components.

```
<Router>
 <Switch>
   <Route exact path='/' render={props=>(<Component {...props}/>)}/>
 </Switch>
</Router>
```

Inside the child component you can use the history.props.push() method to avoid re-rendering.

```
export default class extends Component {
  static getInitialProps({ query: { city, state } }) {
    return { city: city, state: state };
  }

  componentDidMount() { 
    if (!this.props.city) {
       this.props.history.push('to your route')
    } else {
        if (this.props.city === "augusta") {
          window.location = 'https://www.google.com'
        }
    }
   }

 render() {
     if (!this.props.city ||this.props.city === "augusta"){
       return null
     }else{
        return(
           <div>...</div>
        )
     }

  }
}
```

Comment: I am using nextjs . So, this file is implicitly routed from the pages folder.

Comment: you have tagged your issue with reactjs